# Composite video from C64 not being picked up by a modern Smart TV

Tags: commodore-64

I've purchased a Commodore 64 *"as-is"* from eBay. I tediously cleaned out the interior and removed all chips and dusted them out and put them back together.
Still, no signal. Except for sound.

So, I purchased an RCA video cable with an RF TV connector. Sadly, I should've known that Smart TV is so modern. That it also won't pick up any signal.

### Question

Are there any issues with the Commodore that could be addressed so that I don't have to buy an old television to actually get to use my old machine?

Comment: Did you try connecting the antenna output (cinch) on the C64 to the analog video input (yellow cinch) of the TV set? That won't work. Connect 8-pin DIN to analog in (yellow/red/white cinch) with a cable made for that.

Comment: This is so far a question about the TV, not the computer, as it's the TV not displaying the existing/good signal, isn't it?